# Spring-Boot DB Migration with Flyway vs. Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, flyway

I have recently moved from managing a Rails application to writing a RESTful service using Spring-Boot.

Based on my initial impressions, I decided to use the following tools:

- MySQL (DB - the app I am building will need to manage transactions)
- JPA + Hibernate (This I understood to be essentially like an ORM)
- Flyway (Managing schema)

I started by creating connections to the DB and used Flyway to run a migration to create the initial schema. Now, based on my experience in Rails, I was expecting Hibernate annotations to essentially enable ActiveRecord type behavior.

However, upon further reading, it seems that Hibernate manages the DB directly. So, it would seem that the choice is to use Flyway OR Hibernate. To me, this seems to indicate that once the app is deployed, I will not have a way to explicitly manage migrations, and will have to rely on VCS alone.

Inherently, this does not seem safe to me. Can anyone advise me on the best practices to follow?

Thanks